# Apache POI Excel copy from TXT

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

im having a problem and i'd like to ask for your help. The thing is, i'm trying to  put data from a text file (.txt) into a excel sheet with Apache POI. I copy all the data from txt with no problem, but when I paste into the worksheet cell that is selected, it comes with all values inside the cell I choose (of course, that is what i ordered to do).

When I do it manually, open txt file, create new excel file, ctrl+c txt file, ctrl+v on excel sheet, it cames all tabbed right in place, just how I wish I could do.
The txt file is tabbed, so excel understand that it needs to be on another columns.
I have no problems with codding it at all, cuz there is no error or something, and manually I can do it on 3 different ways.

Code I use to copy from txt.

```
String all= "";
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\arquivo.txt"))) {
     String sCurrentLine;
     while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        all = all + "\n" + sCurrentLine;
    }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Code used to set value to excel.

```
String fileName = "C:/Testing.xls";
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Teste");
HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) 0);
row.createCell(0).setAsActiveCell();
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
workbook.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

The thing i'd like to know is: there are any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the input text, then create rows and cells based on what that text contains.
Try something like this:

```
    LinkedList<String[]> text_lines = new LinkedList<>();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\arquivo.txt"))) {
        String sCurrentLine;
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text_lines.add(sCurrentLine.split("\\t"));                 
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String fileName = "C:/Testing.xls";
    Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Teste");
    int row_num = 0;
    for(String[] line : text_lines){
        Row row = sheet.createRow(row_num++);
        int cell_num = 0;
        for(String value : line){
            Cell cell = row.createCell(cell_num++);
            cell.setCellValue(value);
        }
    }

    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    workbook.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
```

That will read each line of the text file into a `String[]` array split by tab characters (which is the default delimiter in Excel) and places into an ordered list.  You can change the regular expression pattern in the `split` function to whatever suits your text.  The second part iterates over the list of String arrays and writes each list to a row, writing each chunk of the list (word, sentence, number...) into its own cell.

Comment: How are you writing into the file `Testing.xls` in the code?

Comment: @whatthefish: the filewriting part in the questioner's code seemed fine, I added it to the response.

Answer (score 0):

split each line from text file with tabbed delemeter "\t" and write to appropriate cell value.
share your code, so that you will get more helping hands.

Comment: I didn't wanted to delemeter the txt file because sometimes that txt will be very large, so I was trying to avoid that to prevent some performance loss